# Google generating new UserId after every visit (Alpha-Stage)

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I'm trying to personalize the welcome message after a second return of the user into my app. To identify the User I save the "userId" which is generated and sent by google in the Action-Request.

It works all fine in the simulator where the userID looks something like this:

```
ABwppHGLJJ-odPadAddq-HOIqpS_tee0jFGJsMV5r-uTCaC9_4Hpz9hi-7YR9823Ulf9PkO7AWJjsotr0989A
```

When I test my Alpha-App on a real device, the "userId" is always same to the conversationId. Both ID's change on the next visit, which makes it impossible to identify the User.

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "1529659908330",
    "locale": "de-DE",
    "lastSeen": "2018-06-22T09:31:45Z"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "1529659908330",
    "type": "ACTIVE",
    "conversationToken": "[]"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
...
...
..
}
```

Is this a normal behavior in the Alpha stage? Will this behavior change after the App is released to Beta/Production?

I have to mention, that the action is not released yet (Alpha).

> //Edit: The "userId" is a Unixtimestamp in miliseconds

Comment: Can you store data in the `conv.user.storage` that is persistent? Does `conv.user.last.seen` always remain undefined? What device are you using for testing?

Comment: I use the official Google Home Mini device.

Comment: Did you do voice matching to match your account to the device? If not, the Mini will not guarantee that the same person is using the action every time.

Answer (score 0):

Note: [userId](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#User.FIELDS.user_id) is deprecated.

As Nick mentioned, you can use userStorage to remember a user. This should give you all information you need around [Saving Data in a Conversation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data).

However, the content of user storage is cleared at the end of conversation if...

- Voice Match is set up but the user couldn't be matched (e.g. background noise or whatever)
- The user disabled personal data

Hope this helps.